# How to avoid json decoding in phoenix while sending json response?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For example, I have an API client that returns json (as a string, not decoded). Currently, I have to do something like this

```
def show(conn, params) do
  {:ok, json} = ApiClient.fetch(params["options"])

  json conn, Poison.decode!(json)
end
```

If I avoid `Poison.decode` then the response will be a huge string instead of json. Can I omit `Poison.decode` somehow? It looks as an excessive action for me.

Note: I'm on phoenix 1.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [json/2](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#json/2) function can send any serializable data structure as JSON (including a string).

Your APIClient.fetch function is not JSON decoding the response, however if the string is already JSON, there is no need to decode it. You can send it directly using [send_resp/3](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_resp/3):

```
send_resp(conn, 200, json)
```

You may also need to set the content type using [put_resp_content_type/3](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_content_type/3):

```
conn
|> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
|> send_resp(200, json)
```

Since the `json/2` function encodes the data as JSON, assuming the JSON string:

```
"{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
```

You would be encoding it twice, resulting in:

```
"\"{\\\"hello\\\":\\\"world\\\"}\""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where did you get that `send_resp/4` function? I can't find it in docs.

Comment: And `put_resp_content_type` is also missing. I'm on Phoenix 1.3.0

Comment: These come from plug https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_resp_content_type/3 - I've added the links to my answer.